# Using master-master mysql db replication in Yii

Tags: mysql, yii, database-replication

I have two servers where I have setup mysql master-master db replication to balance the db load.

```
'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'rootpass',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
```

The question I have is, will mysql itself determine when to use which master db ? If not, will I have to connect both of my master dbs (How do I use this then in my application)?

Can someone point me in the right direction ?
Thanks.

Comment: Since it is a master-master replication, You can execute your queries on both the servers, and the changes that you make will reflect on the other server irrespective of the nature of query, provided they are correctly configured as masters.

Comment: @Dexter_09 How do I use both the databases in my Yii application?